# Can I fetch blog posts from a Gatsby site?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

**Summary**

I have two separate sites that are independent of each other. One is my blog and the other is my portfolio.

My blog is created using Gatsby and my portfolio is standard HTML and CSS bundled with Parcel.

I'm currently creating a new portfolio using Gatsby and wanted to include a section where I showcase my 3 most recent blog posts from my Gatsby blog.

**Goal**

Somehow fetch my top 3 blog posts from my Gatsby site to be displayed on my portfolio.

**Current thought**

I want to keep both sites separate as they will have completely different styling and purposes.

I concidered creating my portfolio and adding a blog page to then route my blog using a path prefix. This would allow everything to sit in a central place and I could just query the data needed to display said blog posts.

This was my initial thought, but I am trying to avoid this being that my blog is its own entity and I have plans to greatly expand it. There should be some way to share GraphQL data between sites, but I just haven't stumbled upon it or maybe it's in front of my face and I'm bypassing it.

Comment: You could publish an RSS feed from your gatsby site and in your portfolio only take the three most recent which would be the top three returned from your RSS feed. This [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-an-rss-feed/) describes how to add an RSS feed in Gatsby. If you're using MDX you will want [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-feed-mdx/) plugin instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

With help from @chrisotto6 , I managed to find a solution that ended up being pretty straight forward.

On my Gatsby blog, I used the [gatsby-plugin-feed](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-feed/) plugin to add an RSS feed. I'm using markdown for my blog posts, so I didn't need to worry about MDX.

The Gatsby docs were straight forward, but if you're still left wanting more, as I was, you can check out these two articles and the following video.

[How to Generate RSS feed with Gatsby.ks](https://www.thirdrocktechkno.com/blog/how-to-generate-RSS-feed-with-gatsby-js/)

[RSS feed with images in Gatsby](https://www.ankursheel.com/blog/adding-an-rss-feed-with-images-to-a-gatsby-site)

[Video: RSS feed using MDX in Gatsby](http://Configure%20RSS%20feed%20with%20MDX%20in%20Gatsby)

Once the RSS feed was set, I used an npm package called [rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser) to parse the xml and use it on my portfolio site.